Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory when creating a new Ruby on Rails App
I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm trying out creating an app using it.
I've installed ruby using RubyInstaller (ver 3.3.0) for Windows and have installed Rails.
I've double checked in CMD for the version of Ruby and Rails installed.
  C:\Windows\System32>ruby --version
  ruby 3.3.0 (2023-12-25 revision 5124f9ac75) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
  C:\Windows\System32>rails --version
  Rails 7.1.3.2

But when I tried to create a new app using Rails I keep getting this error:
  C:\>rails new schedule_tweet
  create
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  .ruby-version
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  .gitattributes
  create  Gemfile
  C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-      7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:733:in ``': No such file or directory - git config       init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:733:in `user_default_branch'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:737:in `git_init_command'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:25:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:87:in `version_control'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:150:in `public_send'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:150:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:346:in `create_root_files'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/base.rb:584:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:28:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/command.rb:28:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:178:in `invoke_command'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/thor-1.3.1/lib/thor.rb:527:in `dispatch'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:73:in `perform'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:71:in `block in invoke'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:149:in `with_argv'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:69:in `invoke'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:127:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/railties-7.1.3.2/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/rails:32:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/rails:32:in `<main>'

I've tried going into the Ruby install directory to check if the file app_base.rb exists and sure enough it does.
I've tried manually adding ruby into the environment variable Path, I've also tried re-installing Ruby, installing a different version of Ruby but nothing works.

You are missing a git client. Go to https://gitforwindows.org/ install it and run rails again.
